# Facade pattern and Object State

Tags: oop, design-patterns

An object should have a state and behaviour.
When implementing the facade pattern the facade object is usually missing the state and only has behaviour.

Is this something accepted for this kind of pattern ?
This is an open question so pls provide more info then yes/no

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is in the body of the question. Facade is useless for it's own and always comes with another object which indeed has a state. Facade only augments the coupled object interface. So yes, it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such rule as "An object should *always* have a state and behavior". On the contrary, there are some patterns, that recommend that Your objects have little or no state (like [Stateless Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_statelessness_principle)) and little or no behavior (like [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)). As to the Facade design pattern, I believe it doesn't explicitly say anything about its state and behavior, so it's up to You how You implement it, but mostly it just doesn't require any state...

Answer (score 0):

Facades may have state as they may have to do some work on their own, e.g. audit logging or statistics generation.

If they do not need state that's perfectly acceptable as well.